# How can I sort and list the word frequency in the second column?

Tags: sorting, multiple-columns, uniq

My data input looks like this:

```
1RDD4_00022_02842   o220
1RDD4_00024_03137   o132
1RDD4_00035_05208   o216
1RDD4_00045_05573   o132
1RDD4_00046_02134   o132
1RDD4_00051_04040   o154
```

In numerical order, I want to sort and list the frequency of words in the right column so the output looks like this:

```
    o132 3
    o154 1
    o216 1
    o220 1
```

I've tried the following pipeline, but it only works on the input's left column, and I don't know how to modify for the right column:

```
sed 's/\.//g;s/\(.*\)/\L\1/;s/\ /\n/g' inputfile | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
cat inputfile | cut -f2
```

or

```
cat inputfile | awk '{print $2}'
```

(heavy)
to select second column only

```
cat inputfile | cut -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```